# Dateformat for ajax calendar extender to create (e.g.) 1980/01/01?

Tags: c#, date-format, calendarextender

I have tried yyyy/MM/dd but this returns 1980/1/1, which will fail the check against cultureinfo format in .NET

Comment: Can you paste a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

try with this it adds the 0 so you will have 1980/01/01

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(1980, 01, 01);
 string result = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", dt);
```

hope it helps

Comment: I should add that for consistency through out the site and to match the regex validators on the front end, I really need the format to be 1980/01/01 from the calendar extender.